# Elementary estimates of two exponential type integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How can I prove that the following estimates hold?

- $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \xi^{\alpha}e^{-\frac{|\xi|^2}{4t}} d\xi \le C_1 t^{-\alpha/2},$$
- $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{x}{t}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} dx \le C_2 t^{-1/2},$$

($\alpha>0$, $\xi, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in \mathbb{R}_+$), where $C_1, C_2$ are constants independent of $t$.

Comment: @thb What do you mean?

Comment: what does $\xi^\alpha$ mean?

Comment: @zhw. $\alpha$ is a positive number.

Comment: What is a vector to a positive number supposed to mean? You also have the vector $x$ in your second integral.

Comment: @zhw.: I had the same question, but I think that it's just a norm. In other words, this is real analysis, not complex.

Comment: Whats the context of this question? Is it related to fourier transforms?

Comment: The $\alpha/2$ looks to me like a hint to solve this Rayleigh-style, as the product of two integrals—one in $x$, one in $y$—converting to polar coordinates before integrating.

Comment: @zhw. every entry of the vector elevated to the number.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Yes ($L^1$ estimates of the derivatives of the heat kernel)

Comment: That makes no sense because entries in the vector can be negative.

Comment: The second integral is zero by anti-symmetry.

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli No it doesn't. I'm very familiar with mulitindex notation. But $\alpha >0$ means $\alpha$ is a positive real number, not a multi-index. Note we have $t^{-\alpha/2}$ on the right.